# How to compare only the time component of DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, time, range, jodatime

Currently I have a simple piece of code which accepts three 'Joda' DateTime objects and performs logic to check if a datetime lies within a datetime range(see below)

```
private boolean isDateWithinPeriod(DateTime d1, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    if (d1.isAfter(startDate) && d1.isBefore(endDate)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I would like this method to do, is only consider the times of the DateTime objects so that when it does the range check, it doesnt take into account the date component. This is so that regardless of what day it is, the time is ultimately driving what the return value is.
For example, consider the below parameters:

```
d1        = 03/07/2015 22:00:00 BST
startDate = 02/07/2015 22:00:00 BST
endDate   = 03/07/2015 17:00:00 BST
```

If passed into the method, the return value would be false because d1 lies outside the startDate to endDate range. If it was to purely compare by time, the range of 22:00:00 to 17:00:00 should allow the method to return true because the d1 time of 22:00:00 is effectively within the range.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: So change the date components of the DateTime object to a fixed date, such as 01/01/1900 or something.

Comment: Side note:

instead of: `if (stuff) return true; else return false;`

just: `return stuff;`

Comment: If you want to compare the local times, then call `.toLocalTime()` on each before comparing.   But also, you are saying that the start time is greater than the end time, so do you mean that this is a range of time that goes over midnight? Or something else?

Comment: Also consider that Joda's `DateTime` has a time zone.  What if they're in two different time zones?  Do you want to normalize them first?

Comment: A `DateTime` is a date ___and___ a time. If you are only interested in the time part, why not just use a `LocalTime` instead. It does not have a date part. And it also does not have a time zone. You can come from `DateTime` to `LocalTime` with the `toLocalTime()` method, of course.